# Does IIS URL Rewrite have Proxy_Intercept_Errors (like Nginx)

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module, arr

After posting this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891667/how-to-ignore-a-rule-if-the-rewrite-page-is-not-200-ok-status

I stumbled across this:
[nginx as load balancer server out 404 page based on HTTP response from app server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244250/nginx-as-load-balancer-server-out-404-page-based-on-http-response-from-app-serve)

Which, correct me if I'm wrong but, basically says Nginx can do what I need using

[`proxy_intercept_errors`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) (From nginx.org)

**Determines whether proxied responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be redirected to nginx for processing with the error_page directive.**

---

**Yes!**

This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Does IIS7.5 URL Rewrite 2.0 + ARR have this functionality? Or is this something that is exclusive for Nginx servers only?

Comment: Outbound response rewrite rules? send to custom error page...? not sure what you mean (not familiar with nginx)

Comment: Problem is once sent to a custom error page, it can't get back into the URL Rewrite engine without doing a redirect--I want to avoid this.

Comment: So rewrite back to original request/farm?

Comment: Using what? The custom error page?